# Destructors and constructors

Tags: c++

Would someone please explain to me why I get an "Error: not declared in this scope?"

num and denom are private members of class Rationalnumber.

Thanks!

```
Rationalnumber::Rationalnumber(){
num = 0;
denom = 1;
int * n = new int;
int * d = new int;
*n = num;
*d = denom;
}

Rationalnumber::~Rationalnumber(){
delete n;
}
```

Comment: But n isn't part of the class, you cant use it on the destructor without declaring it

Comment: For future reference, please include the rest of the class definition when asking for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rationalnumber::~Rationalnumber(){
delete n;
}
```

Is `n` a member of the class? If not, then it will give error, as `n` is neither declared in the destructor, nor is it a member of the class.

You've declared `n` in the constructor however, but that is *local* to the constructor only.The destructor (or any other function) cannot access that variable (which is declared in another function or constructor).

Answer (score 3):

`n` is a local variable in the class constructor. When it goes out of scope when the constructor completes, it is no longer visible to any other part of your application; that memory has been leaked.

There's no local or member variable called `n` at the point at which the destructor is called, hence: not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 2):

"n" is a local variable in the constructor.

You probably want it to be a member variable in the class:

```
class Rationalnumber {
    int* n;
    int* d;
    .........
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You define n in the scope of your constructor. This code is so simple that you shouldn't even `new` and `delete` ints. Just store `n` and `d` as class members. Your code, even fixed, would leak d as you new it but don't delete it.